# How do we call in English scientific terms the Fermat's principle about back and forth light traversal?

Tags: optics, visible-light, soft-question, terminology, geometric-optics

We know that the path followed by the light from point A to point B is independent of the direction of propagation of light. This is what is called in French "[le principe de retour inverse de la lumière](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principe_de_Fermat#Principe_du_retour_inverse_de_la_lumi.C3.A8re)".
What do we call this in English scientific terms?

Comment: Do you mean "reciprocity"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocity_(electromagnetism)

Comment: I guess it is, but it sounded too complicated for me to assure it fits the context I'm concerned with

Comment: OK... given John Rennie's answer I am not sure that I have what you are looking for.

Comment: My 9th grade physics text in the chapter of refraction simply says Principle  of  Reversibility  of  the  path  of  light.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a universally agreed phrase to describe this, but I think the closest is [the principle of geometrical reversibility](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=principle%20of%20geometrical%20reversibility).